# Continuity of the Second Moment of a Continuous Stochastic Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, continuity

Given a continuous stochastic process with respect to time with finite variance at a given $t$. Does it necessarily imply the second moment and variance are continuous in time?

Comment: You need to define what you mean by continuous stochastic process (i.e., continuous sample paths w.p. 1? continuous state space?)

Comment: @Liron: I said "a continuous stochastic process with respect to time". It could be with probability $1$ or for every path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the probability space $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure. Choose continuous functions $f_n: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ such that $\text{supp} \, f_n \subseteq (2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n})=: I_n$ and $f_n(I_n) = [0,1]$. We set

$$X_t(\omega) := \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 2^{n/2} 1_{I_n}(\omega) f_n(t), \qquad \omega \in [0,1].$$

Then $t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is continuous for each $\omega \in [0,1]$ and $X_0(\omega)=0$. In particular, $\|X_0\|_2=0$. On the other hand, we can choose $t_n \in I_n$ such that $f_n(t_n)=1$ and therefore $$\|X_{t_n}\|_{L^2} = \|2^{n/2} 1_{I_n}\|_{L^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$ This shows $\|X_t\|_{L^2} \not \to \|X_0\|_{L^2}$ as $t \to 0$. Since $$\mathbb{E}(X_{t_n}) = \|2^{n/2} 1_{I_n}\|_{L^1} = 2^{n/2} 2^{-n+1} \to 0 \qquad \text{as} \, \, n \to \infty$$ we also get $\text{var}(X_{t}) \not \to \text{var}(X_0)=0$ as $t \to 0$.

**Remark:** It follows from Fatous lemma that the inequality $$\|X_t\|_{L^2} \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \|X_{t_n}\|_{L^2}$$ holds for any sequence $(t_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $t_n \to t$.

Comment: Excellent! But could you please add your answer for variance for completeness? See also my question and the corresponding answer and response in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570635/the-continuity-of-the-expectation-of-a-continuous-stochastic-procees/570685#570685.

Comment: @Hans Where is the problem? Just calculate the expectation $\mathbb{E}X_t$...

Comment: It is an easy one liner. That was why I said "for completeness" sake, since I asked for variance. I can add it if you do not care to. It is in case someone is looking the answer, just as you provided a reference for my proof in the expectation of a stochastic process problem.

Comment: @Hans I see your point; I'll add it to my answer. (I was wondering whether you have problems to calculate the expectation.)

Comment: Saz: Have you seen my new and related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134503/the-continuity-of-correlation-coefficient-of-a-continuous-stochastic-process?

Comment: @Hans Yes, I have seen it, but I don't find it that interesting ...

Comment: Why do you think that? Is it because it is more complicated? I think it is interesting because correlation is a measure of dependency.

Comment: @Hans Actually it's the other way round: Usually I find complicated questions more interesting. You are right, correlation measures dependenceny, but in my oppinion it's not a "good" measure. If the correlation equals $0.5$, what does this tell me? Okay, they are not (fully) (in)dependent, but besides of that?