# Approximation Lemma in the construction of Ito Integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am self-learning basic stochastic calculus. In my book, the author first defines the Ito integral for simple step adapted processes and then extends it to a larger class $\mathcal{L}_{c}^{2}(T)$ of integrands. This class has processes $(X_t:t\geq 0)$ satisfying:

(1) $X_t$ is adapted.

(2) The norm of $X_t$:

$$\int_{0}^{T}E[X_t^2]dt < \infty$$

(3) $(X_t)$ is almost surely continuous.

We proceed by verifying the below claim.

> **Approximation Lemma**. Let $X\in \mathcal{L}_{c}^{2}(T)$. Then, there exists a sequence $(X^{(n)})$ of simple step adapted processes in $S(T)$, such that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{T} \mathbf{E}[(X_{t}^{(n)} - X_t)^2]dt = 0$$

My book is terse, so I want to expand on the steps.

(1) Does an $\epsilon-\delta$ style proof for step $1$ make sense, and is it rigorous?
(2) How do I apply DCT in step $2$?

***Proof.***

(1) For a given $n$, consider the partition $\{\frac{jT}{2^{n}},\frac{(j+1)T}{2^{n}}\}$ and the simple step adapted process given by :

$$X_{t}^{(n)}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}X_{t_{j}}\mathbf{1}_{(t_{j},t_{j+1}]}(t)$$

In other words, we give the constant value $X_{t_{j}}$ on the whole
interval $(t_{j},t_{j+1}]$. By continuity of paths of $X$, it is
clear that $X_{t}^{(n)}(\omega)\to X_{t}(\omega)$ at any $t\leq T$
and for any $\omega$.

$(\star)$ **Justification**.

Let $A$ be the set of all $\omega$, such that $\lim_{t\to s}X(t,\omega)=X(s,\omega)$.Then, $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$.

Pick an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ and fix a point $s\in[0,T]$. By definition of continuity, $(\forall\omega\in A)$, $(\exists\delta>0)$ such that $|t-s|<\delta$ implies $|X_{t}-X_{s}|<\epsilon$. By the Archimedean property, there exists $N\in\mathbf{N}$, such that $\frac{1}{2^{N}}<\delta$.

Consider $(X^{(n)}:n\geq N)$. There exists a sequence of dyadic intervals $I_{N}\subseteq I_{N+1}\subseteq\ldots$ containing the point $s$.

Thus, the process $X^{(n)}$ takes the (random) but constant value
$X_{\frac{jT}{2^{n}}}^{(n)}$ on the interval $\frac{jT}{2^{n}}<t\leq\frac{(j+1)T}{2^{n}}$.

For all $n\geq N$, since $l(I_{n})<\delta$, it follows that $|X_{\frac{jT}{2^{n}}}-X_{s}|<\epsilon$. But, $X^{(n)}$ takes the value $X_{\frac{jT}{2^{n}}}$ over $\left(\frac{jT}{2^{n}},\frac{(j+1)T}{2^{n}}\right]$. So, for all $n\geq N$, $X_{s}^{(n)}=X_{\frac{jT}{2^{n}}}$. Consequently, for all $n\geq N$, $\left|X_{s}^{(n)}-X_{s}\right|<\epsilon$.

This is true for all $\omega\in A$. Thus, $X_{t}^{(n)}\xrightarrow{a.s.}X_t$. $\blacksquare$

(2) Therefore, by the dominated convergence theorem, we have:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{T} \mathbf{E}[(X_t^{(n)} - X_t)^2] dt = 0$$

($\star$) **Justification**.

For any $t \in [0,T]$, $X_{t}^{(n)} \to X_{t}$ almost surely. Since almost sure convergence implies $L^2-$convergence, it follows that for any $t \in [0,T]$,

$$\mathbf{E}[(X_t^{(n)} - X_t)^2] \to 0$$

I am not sure how to go from here. DCT has a certain bound condition that needs to be fulfilled, before we can write:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{T} \mathbf{E}[(X_{t}^{(n)} - X_t)^2]dt = 0$$

So, any inputs would help.

Comment: Could you share the book you are using?

Comment: It is *A first course in stochastic calculus* by LP Arguin. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Course-Stochastic-Calculus-Applied-Undergraduate/dp/1470464888

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: In general almost sure convergence does not imply L2 convergence (even on a probability space,) so you can't conclude what you did in the second justification.

Comment: I think you can first assume $X_t$ is uniformly bounded (i.e., $\exists M$ s.t. $\forall \omega, |X_t(\omega)| \leq C.$ Then, you can apply dominated convergence as the book says since $|X^(n)(\omega)| \leq M$ and we have almost sure convergence. 

For $X_t$ continuous but not uniformly bounded, truncate. Look at $X_t \wedge M$. As $M \to \infty$, these functions are dominated by $X_t$ and converge almost surely to $X_t$, so use dominated convergence. Then approximate $X_t \wedge M$ by your step function.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed, suppose we assume that $(\exists M)$, $(\forall \omega)$, s.t. $|X_t(\omega)|\leq M$. Why does that imply that the step processes $X_{t}^{(n)}(\omega)$ are also bounded? 

Also, does the proof for almost-sure convergence make sense?

Comment: If for all $t$, $|X_t(\omega)| \leq M$, then $|X^{(n)}_s(\omega)| = |X_{t_{j+1}}(\omega)| \leq M$ ($s \in (t_j, t_{j+1}].$) So boundedness follows trivially. 

Your proof for almost sure convergence is correct.

Comment: Is the (convergence) proof of step (1) correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to write an answer to more clearly explain what I was trying to say. As written, this does prove the assertion that bounded simple processes are dense in the space $\mathcal{L}_c^2(T)$, but not that the specific sequence of simple functions that the author proposes converges to $X_t$ in the $L^2$ sense.

We first prove the approximation lemma for $X_t$ that satisfies the above 3 conditions, and satisfies a boundedness condition:
$$\exists M | \forall t \geq 0, a.s. \; \omega \in \Omega \quad |X_t(\omega)| \leq M.$$

In this case, $$X^{(n)}_t \xrightarrow{a.s} X_t$$
by the proof you gave above.

For verifying the second claim, note that under these assumptions
$$(X_t^{(n)}(\omega) - X_t(\omega))^2 \leq (2M)^2$$
almost surely
and that $\int_0^T \mathbb{E}[(2M)^2] dt < \infty.$
By dominated convergence, the second claim follows: for $|X_t(\omega)| \leq M$,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^T \mathbb{E}[(X_t - X^{(n)})^2]dt = 0. \tag{(A)}.$$

For simplicity's sake, assume $X_t$ is a nonnegative process. To extend the result, note that almost surely for all $\omega$ and for all $t \geq 0$,
$$\lim_{M \to \infty} M \wedge X_t(\omega) = X_t(\omega).$$
It's also straightforward to verify that $$|(X_t(\omega) - M \wedge X_t(\omega)|^2 \leq |X_t(\omega)|^2.$$
Further, since $\int_0^T \mathbb{E}[(X_t)^2] dt < \infty$, we will apply dominated convergence to conclude
$$\lim_{M \to \infty} \int_0^T \mathbb{E}[(X_t - M \wedge X_t)^2] dt = 0 \tag{(B)}.$$

At this point, the book claims to prove the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^T \mathbb{E}[(X_t - X^{(n)})^2]dt = 0$ using the definition above. However, I will construct a different sequence of simple functions $Y^{(n)}_t$ that approximate $X_t$.

Fix $\epsilon_n= 2^{-n} > 0.$ From line $(B),$ there exists $M_n > 0$ large enough such that
$$\int_0^T \mathbb{E}[(X_t - M \wedge X_t)^2]dt < \epsilon_n.$$

By line $(A)$, there exists an $N_n > 0$ such that
$$\int_0^T \mathbb{E}[(M_n \wedge X_t - M_n \wedge X^{(N_n)}_t)^2] dt < \epsilon_n.$$

It follows that $Y^{(n)}_t := M_n \wedge X^{(N_m)}_t$ is close to $X_t$ in the $L_2$ sense, i.e.,

$$\int_0^T \mathbb{E}[(X_t - Y^{(n)}_t)^2]dt \leq 4\epsilon_n = 4\cdot 2^{-n}.$$

Note: the book proposes a different sequence of simple functions, but I don't see how they are bounded, let alone dominated above by $X_t$. If we just let $X_t(\omega) = 1-t$, it's clear that $X^{(n)}_t \geq X_t$.

If we know that $\mathbb{E}[X_t^2]$ was continuous (which is not a guarantee, see [The continuity of the expectation of a continuous stochastic procees](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570635/the-continuity-of-the-expectation-of-a-continuous-stochastic-procees)), we could perhaps conclude something, but I am not sure that the statement in the book holds without some argument more sophisticated than dominated convergence. Perhaps the author omitted an assumption.

If we assume a bound on the process like that of the Kolmogorov continuity criterion, (see [Density of L2 simple processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4578678/density-of-l2-simple-processes,)) the simple functions given in this question will approximate the process. However, it's not a guarantee that our process is this nice.

Comment: One question about the application of Dominated Convergence to $|X_t - X_t^{(n)}|^2$. Doesn't DCT say that, if $X^{(n)} \to X$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s., and $|X_n|\leq Y$ with $\mathbf{E}[Y]<\infty$, then $\lim \mathbf{E} [X_n] = \mathbf{E}[\lim X_n]= \mathbf{E}[X]$? 

It seems that, you are saying, both $\mathbf{E}[\cdot]$ and $\int$ operators preserve limits.

Comment: Dominated convergence is a more general theorem. In this case I am using it on the product measure of $\mathbb{P} \times dm$, where $dm$ is the lebesgue measure on $[0,T]$. But yes, the expectation operator and the integral operator both preserve limits.